# CK Finder - Browse server button gives "Folder not found. Please refresh and try again." error

Tags: ckfinder

I need to use CKFinder with CKEditor. 
I integrated it with  CKEditor but when I click "Bwowse Server" button, it gives me error - "Folder not found. Please refresh and try again.".

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check you have provided proper path. Also check permissions on the folder you specified—sometimes it happens just because of permissions not given to folder.

Comment: Disha your answer could be greatly improved by explaining where to provide the proper path within the Drupal UI.